# Find the value of $\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2} 1$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the value of:

$$\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2} 1$$

Comment: The inner sum equals $i_2$. Is that clear to you?

Comment: Start from the inside and work your way outwards. $\sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2} 1$ becomes $i_2$ as mentioned by the above comment. Now look at $\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1} i_2$

Comment: "I have no idea what it represents?" Then stop wondering and just compute it. *Afterwards*, you will come back to what the sum means, if you still want to do so...

Comment: @Did: The problem may look intimidating if one takes $n=100$ (say) and goes summing up to $i_{50}$. However, the idea of what that would represent would make the problem very easy to solve. But as you said, start with basics: first solve for one $\Sigma$, then for $\Sigma\Sigma$. By the time you are done with $\Sigma\Sigma\Sigma$, you will have enough ideas to see through the problem, what it represents, and then you can directly go for $\Sigma\Sigma\Sigma...\Sigma$. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}\sum_{i_3=1}^{i_2} 1 = \sum_{i_1=1}^n\sum_{i_2=1}^{i_1}i_2 = \sum_{i_1=1}^n\frac{i_1(i_1+1)}{2}&=& \frac{1}{2} \left( \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6} +\frac {n(n+1)}{2} \right) \\=\color{orange}{    \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12}(2n+1+3)}  &=&\color{blue}{ \frac{n(n+1)(n+2)}{6}}.
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Thanks. So, the given notation represents the sum of the cubes of first  $n$ natural numbers. But how do we see it without using combinatorics?

Comment: The sum in the question represents a tetrahedron. The sum of the cubes is given by
\begin{eqnarray*}
\sum_{i=1}^n i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I am sorry. That was as stupid as it could get. Realized my mistake after posting my comment. I am sorry, indeed.

Answer (score 3):

Equivalently, we are counting the number of $(x,y,z)\in \mathbf{Z}^3$ such that $1\le x\le y\le z\le n$. Set $a=x,$ $b=y+1,$ and $c=z+2$. Then the result is the number of $(a,b,c) \in \mathbf{Z}^3$ such that
$
1\le a<b<c\le n+2,
$ 
which is clearly 
$$
\binom{n+2}{3}.
$$

Comment: Now I do understand the problem. Thank you.

Comment: You can find a similar problem here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1668773/number-of-k-tuples-such-that-1-le-i-1-le-i-2-le-le-i-k-le-n?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. It means that my problem is same as finding the number of 3-multisets that can be formed out of a set of $n$ numbers. And that is equivalent to the dot-bar problem of arranging $n-1$ dots and 3 bars.